# Given that the volume of the parallelepiped with sides →$AB=(5,5,8), →AC=(4,-1,4)$ and $→AD=(-9,-1,a)$ is $89 \text{ u}^3$, find $a$.

Tags: geometry

Q. Given that the volume of the parallelepiped with sides →$AB=(5,5,8), →AC=(4,-1,4)$ and $→AD=(-9,-1,a)$ is $89 \text{ u}^3$, find $a$.

---

I attempted to solve this question by finding area of one side then multiplying this by the height but this resulted in a negative $a^2$, which is clearly incorrect. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have attached my working out below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the area you could have used the cross product of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ (its length gives you the area).
Likewise, the volume can be expressed as the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix constructed from the three vectors for the sides involved.

But it seems that in your approach you want to find the height (or better, distance) of the point D to the ABC plane, which is arguably the most straightforward approach. You could also use a determinant trick for that purpose, but more straigthforward would be to start with the vector $\vec{AD}$ and project out any components parallel to $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$, in order to end up with a vector from D to the plane which is perpendicular to the plane. So it would seem that the "height" you want is obtained as the $\vec{H}$ by these steps:
$$
\vec{X} = \vec{AB} - \left(\frac{\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{AC}}{|\vec{AC}|^2}\right) \vec{AC} $$
and
$$
\vec{H} = \vec{AD} - \left(\frac{\vec{AD}\cdot\vec{AB}}{|\vec{AB}|^2}\right) \vec{AB}
- \left(\frac{\vec{AD}\cdot\vec{X}}{|\vec{X}|^2}\right) \vec{X}
$$
where the first step projects out $\vec{AC} $ from $\vec{AB} $ to get two perpendicular vectors in the ABC plane, and then the second step projects out these two vectors from $\vec{AD}$. (This cannot be done in one step if $\vec{AB} $ and $ \vec{AC}$ aren't perpendicular to begin with, that's why I had to edit this answer and create $\vec{X}$ first!)
I leave it up to you to fill in the rest.